# Implementing IDisposable for WCF ChannelFactory<T>

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a web service which is used to take requests from a website and extract data from a database to return to the website.  It all seems to work fine, but there has been something that has been bugging me since we developed it.  My code for establishing the connection to the service from the client is as follows:

```
string bindingName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BindingName"];
ChannelFactory<IIntranet> factory = new ChannelFactory<IIntranet>(bindingName);
IIntranet proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Now the proxy exposes all of the methods in my interface, but one thing it doesn't do is implement IDisposable.  So after a bit of googling I found various people saying we had to implement the interface, which I did as follows:

```
public class Service : IInternet, IIntranet, IDisposable
```

The IDisposable provides the Dispose method, which is as follows:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

The dispose method was one I copied from the internet and looks like:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I have is that the compiler doesn't recognise State, Close or Abort as being valid keywords.  I can resolve State and it goes to System.Activities.Debugger which doesn't seem right to me at all and the others just don't resolve at all.

I have included System.ServiceModel, System.ServiceModel.Web and System.ServiceModel.Channels and these don't seem to resolve it.

So my questions are:

> 1) Am I implementing IDisposable correctly for the scenario above (website creating service connections to retrieve data)
>   2) If so then how can I resolve the errors in the Disposing method?

Any help appreciated.

## Update

Just for reference - what I am looking to do is something like the following:

```
using (IIntranet proxy = factory.CreateChannel())
{  
}
```

Comment: just FYI: because of the (IMO majorly buggy) Dispose implementation for ClientChannels, Microsoft recommends you *do not use* using statements with WCF channels.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Seems a bit of a half-a*sed implementation for something that should be straightforward!

Comment: With the update: Why are you using the channel directly instead of the client class? In [my example](https://github.com/AndersAbel/coding.abel.nu/blob/master/TestLib/Service%20References/CalculatorClient/Reference.cs) I'm using the `CalculatorClient` class - never the `ICalculatorChannel` interface which I regard as internal infrastructure.

Comment: We have two interfaces, IIntranet and IInternet and depending on the app we are using (web facing or internal) we use a different interface.  As far as I can see the service (called Service confusingly) isn't exposed through my service reference.

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps copy [my dispose implementation](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/using-and-disposing-of-wcf-clients/)?

In that case it is meant to be added as a partial for the `someServiceClient` class generated by the "add service reference" command in visual studio. It is not meant to be use with the `ChannelFactory<T>` class.

It might be possible to make a similar solution for `ChannelFactory<T>` but the code will probably not (as you've found out) work with anytyhing else than the Wcf Client proxy (which inherits from `ClientBase<T>`).

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I've just checked and it was indeed that one.  Back to the drawing board then I think!

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a wrong idea to dispose the service from a client. Because you cannot control when your service will be disposed. The proper way is to dispose it from the server side when you want to close the service.
2. The `State` property belongs to `IClientChannel` interface. So you can use it like that : `((IClientChannel)proxy).State`

Comment: Hi Jacob,  Sorry I might not have made myself clear.  I'm not trying to dispose from the client - I create the channel from the client, but I'd like to be able to wrap it in an using statement so that the proxy is disposed by the server when it is finished

Comment: Ok. So you need to implement the IDisposable on the proxy, not on the service. Then the client will dispose the proxy after using it, not the server.

Comment: The proxy is created as an instance of IIntranet, which is defined in the class called service and this is where I have been trying to implement IDisposable.